# BeautifulSoup ingests all data but .findAll() returns only the links of one parent

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup in Python. All data is ingested, including all the links I am trying to get to. However, when I use the .findAll() function it returns only a part of the links I am looking for. That is to say only the links in the following xpath are returned

/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]

This ignores the links in
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]
etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamoterna/"
response = requests.get(url)
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
mp_pages = []
mps = content.findAll(attrs = {'class': 'sc-907102a3-0 sc-e6d2fd61-0 gOAsvA jBTDjv'})
for x in mps:
    mp_pages.append(x.get('href'))

print(mp_pages)
```

I expected all links to be appended in the mp_pages list, but it only went down one parent (those starting with A), seemingly stopping at the last child, not continuing.

I have seen similar questions where the answer was using selenium due to javascript, but since all the links are in content, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is stored inside `<script>` element in Json form. To parse it you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamoterna/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text)

# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

all_data = []
for c in data['props']['pageProps']['contentApiData']['commissioners']:
    all_data.append((f'{c["callingName"]} {c["surname"]}', c['url']))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['Name', 'URL'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                              Name                                                                                                                            URL
0                 Fredrik Ahlstedt               https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/fredrik-ahlstedt_8403346f-0f0c-4d48-bbd0-f6b43b368873/
1             Emma Ahlström Köster           https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/emma-ahlstrom-koster_e09d9076-28c7-4583-a17f-7a776de7f01f/
2                  Alireza Akhondi                https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/alireza-akhondi_4099ff9c-5d27-4605-b018-98fb229d94fa/
3                  Anders Alftberg                https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/anders-alftberg_f0d945f3-9449-458e-ba40-1a0da1a72303/
4                   Leila Ali Elmi                 https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/leila-ali-elmi_5997ba96-4f01-46f4-8bd8-e1411a9d503b/
5               Janine Alm Ericson             https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/janine-alm-ericson_7e408079-a5cd-432a-a30e-fd61fd15c65a/
6                    Ann-Sofie Alm                  https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/ann-sofie-alm_f91f6a86-591c-449c-b3dd-1fdaa86338cd/
7                      Sofia Amloh                    https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/sofia-amloh_359e75f3-519e-49d7-b155-ada488e621ea/
8             Andrea Andersson Tay           https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-och-partier/ledamot/andrea-andersson-tay_352b875d-e44d-43f5-bf93-e507770c12de/

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This will solve my practical problem. On the theory: Do you happen to know why BeautifulSoup ingests all the HTML, but findAll() doesn't find all links?

Comment: @Vanpaia Because `beautifulsoup` doesn't parse the `<script>` element and the Json data inside it. It's just HTML/XML parser.